# ORA-13249: SDO_NN cannot be evaluated without using index

Tags: oracle, nearest-neighbor

I have two tables called `my_nodes` and `restaurants` that contain a name and `geoloc` data. I need to get a table that for each my_node returns nearest restaurant and distance from node to restaurant.

```
    select n.node_id, r.r_name , sdo_nn_distance(1) as min_distance from 
        (select nodeid as node_id, geoloc  from my_nodes@my_server ) n,
        (select r_name, GEOLOC from restaurants) r 
        where sdo_nn   (n.geoloc, r.GEOLOC,   'Unit = MILE sdo_num_res = 1', 1) = 'TRUE'
```

The query above returns:

```
    ORA-13249: SDO_NN cannot be evaluated without using index
    ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MD", line 1723
    ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MDERR", line 17
    ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.PRVT_IDX", line 9
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Check this [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3696687) related to your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got same error message, but without DB-Link. http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/154844/ helped (replace c and s with your table aliases and spatial_index with your spatial index name):

```
/*+ LEADING(c) USE_NL(c s) INDEX(s spatial_index)*/
```

Answer (score 0):

`from my_nodes@my_server n` caused the problem. Running the same query on the server with the schema leads to `from my_nodes n` works. Creating an index is an option but it will kill performance due to calls across nodes.